# "How to *verb* this thing *another verb*..." vs. "How to *verb* this thing TO *another verb*..."?

Tags: verbs, particles

Which one from the following two variants is the correct one?

- How to make this thing ***to*** work...?
- How to make this thing work...?

I'm not an English speaker, but for me, the first variant sounds good and I used it until today. However, just today I observed that the second variant is used in many places on the internet.

Comment: *Make* is one of a select few verbs that can take a bare infinitive (an infinitive without *to*).  *Make X to work* isn't strictly ungrammatical, but you are far more likely to hear *make X work*.  Another similar verb is *help,* which is commonly used as both *help X do Y* and *help X to do Y,* with a slight difference in meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second variant is correct in the given example.

Having said that, as is the case with any grammatical construction, there are cases where the same word order would require the first variant, such as "How to teach this child **to** work...?"

*I would also note that your examples have no subject.  Normally you would ask something more like, "How **do I/you** make this thing work?"*